# Android: split a string considering 2 separating characters

Tags: java, android, tokenize

I have a string containing messages. The string looks like this:

```
bill:hello;tom:hi;bill:how are you?;tommy:hello!; ...
```

I need to split the string into several srings, on the characters `:` and `;`.
For now, I have split the string on `;` and i could add the results in list elements.

```
    List<Message> listMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(messages, ";");

    String result = null;
    String uname = "";
    String umess = "";

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

        result = tokenizer.nextToken();
        listMessages.add(new Message(result, ""));

    }
```

I still have to do this on the `:` to have the two resulting strings in my list element, and I tried something like that:

```
    List<Message> listMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(messages, ";");

    String result = null;
    String uname = "";
    String umess = "";

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

        result = tokenizer.nextToken().split(":");
        uname = result[0];
        umess = result[1];
        listMessages.add(new Message(result[0], result[1]));

    }
```

But I got this error, that I don't understand?

```
01-23 17:12:19.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appandroid/com.example.appandroid.ListActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

Thanks in advance to look at my problem.

Comment: Do you want to split the string at the start or after adding to list?

Comment: read the darn documentation. it is like the first line of the javadoc of the tokenizer you are using ...

Comment: @njzk2 I don't understand? I was trying to get requirements from OP so that correct answer could be provided?

Comment: @smit: after. Each list element has a name user X and a message Y. (X:Y;).

Comment: @LocoCo I understand that. I think answer provided below will satisfy your need. If not then let me know waht you want?

Comment: @smit : was not directed to you, sorry for misunderstanding. i was just trying to say that the op is using a function without reading the doc and complaining about how to do something the method doc's states on the first line...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using StringTokenizer, you can use `String.split(regex)` to split based on two delimiters like below:

```
String test="this: bill:hello;tom:hi;bill:how are you?;tommy:hello!;";
String[] arr = test.split("[:;]");
for(String s: arr){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
this
 bill
hello
tom
hi
bill
how are you?
tommy
hello!
```

EDIT:

from @njzk2 comments if you just wanna use StringTokenizer you can use one of its [overloaded constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which takes 2 args .

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(test, ":;");
```

Comment: so in [:;] dont we require an OR operator like [:|;]   ??

Comment: why so complicated ? strintokenizer does that, it just needs to be used properly

Comment: @njzk2 kewl, i am not really aware of StringTokenizer and also heard people saying that using String.split() is more flexi .. anyways thanks :)

Comment: @njzk2 straight from API of StringTokenizer `Breaks a string into tokens; new code should probably use split(String).` link---> http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: @Dennis. No you don't need that. That's the whole point of character class. `[;:]` already means `(:|;)`, whereas, `[:|;]` will mean `(:|[|]|;)`

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR : agreed, but i don't see any justification for this "should probably", nor any depreciation.

Comment: @njzk2 as said earlier, i am not really aware of StringTokenizer class infact i never really used it untill now. :P, but i have seen some `Experts` here on SO suggesting ppl not to use it, again as i said i truly have no knowledge on StringTokenizer class.:P